# Barra header não redirecciona correctamente

Tags: css, bootstrap, header

Num template que estou a usar, ele é todo responsivo em qualquer tamanho.

Sendo que estou a adequa-lo ao meu site, somente na barra header é que não está a funcionar correctamente, conforme mostro no gif.

Se tiver o modo de programador aberto, de imediato em tamanho pequeno, e abrir para tamanho maior, o template corresponde, caso seja de grande para pequeno (como imagem), o mesmo não dá.

O que poderá ser? Já aconteceu-vos?[image: GIF_bootstrap_header_template]

Comment: Verifique se você está com a media viewport corretamente ajustada, segue um exemplo:
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

Comment: Não funcionou.

Uso isto, tal como vem no template, mas não dá.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se sua pagina está tratando o redimensionamento através da meta viewport, segue exemplo

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

Comment: Não funcionou.

Uso isto, tal como vem no template, mas não dá.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: Você pode fornecer o codigo fonte ou a url para que possa ser analisada?